# Fastest way to find the body tag via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On every document ready I need to get the body tag via jQuery and I'm more curious about the answer to this than anything else.

Let's say this is the body tag on every page on my site:

```
<body id="body">
```

Is it faster to query the body tag by just the tag name:

```
$('body')
```

or query it by its id:

```
$('#body')
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The fastest way would be `$(document.body)`.
This doesn't involve any selector parsing.

`$('body')` is much faster (in Firefox and Chrome) than `$('#body')`.

### [Test](http://jsperf.com/body-selection)

Comment: And `$(document.getElementById('body'))` is a [close second best](http://jsperf.com/body-selection/2) - native JS will generally be faster than jQuery functionality.

Comment: Remember to run the test yourself. Now on my Firefox `$('#body')` faster than `$('body')`. And `$(document.getElementById('body'))` is not the fastest.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery optimises the finding of the `body` element. Here's the relevant [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L97):

```
if ( selector === "body" && !context && document.body ) {
    this.context = document;
    this[0] = document.body;
    this.selector = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    return this;
}
```

So using `$("body")` will be pretty much as fast as `$(document.body)`, as suggested in other answers. Using `$("body")` will certainly be faster than giving the `body` an `id`, because if an `id` is used, the above, optimised code cannot run. jQuery will use `getElementById`, which is fast, but not as fast as the above!

**Edit**

As pointed out by @SLaks, `$(document.body)` is the fastest, which makes sense when you look at the jQuery source that will handle a DOM element selector, rather than a string:

```
if ( selector.nodeType ) {
    this.context = this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Measurements indicate that `$(document.body)` is still much faster.  http://jsperf.com/body-selection

Comment: Indeed it is. And that does make perfect sense. The relevant jQuery source to handle that is just above the part I pasted into my answer but I missed it!

Comment: Frozen in time GitHub link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/83c08ffa1ffa778e41d728ed7fa49044dd7135f9/src/core.js#L97-L103 Did not find where the code was moved to.

Answer (score 2):

Tag name is the fastest in Chrome, and probably most browsers.  Faster yet would be to skip the jQuery wrapper:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

Or

```
document.body
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("body") returns an array btw