# find if a img have alt in jquery if not then add from array

Tags: jquery

first need to find all img in the sites

```
$("#body").find(img)
```

and then check if the img have the "alt" attribute, if image have the attribute it'll be escaped and if it not have one or the alt is empty,a string will be randomly added to img from a list or array.

I now that i have to use .each() some how in a function but I'm new to jquery so a little bit help would be perfect.

Comment: How does the array looks like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = ['hello', 'hi', 'yo'];
$('#body img').each(function() {
    if ( ! $(this).attr('alt'))
        $(this).attr('alt', arr[Math.round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1)))]);
});
```

Comment: will this include if alt is a empty string?

Comment: @EhsanPourhadi: Yes it will, this will give you all images that have either no alt or an empty alt, but will skip all images that already have an alt string

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all with one selector:

```
$("#body img[alt!='']").each(function(){
    // What you want here...
});
```

Or this:

```
$("#body img[alt!=''][alt]").each(function(){
```

depends on the DOM structure.

Or with a `filter` function:

```
$("#body img").filter(function(){
    return this.alt;
}).each(function(){
    // What you want here...
});
```

If you want to do it all with one `each`, you can use this:

```
$("#body img").each(function(){
    if (this.alt)
        // Do something.
    else
        // Do something else.
});
```

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706429/fastest-way-to-find-the-body-tag-via-jquery shows that $('body') is significantly faster than $('#body') to get the body object. Similarly, $('img') is 12% faster than $('body').find('img')

Comment: @JoeBowman He's not trying to find the `body` object, hes trying to find the `#body` element..

Comment: @Curt and gdoron: first line of OP states: "first need to find all img in the sites"

Comment: Curt is right, it should be `alt==''` (he wants all images that do not have an alt value)

Comment: @Curt. On which line?, give the whole code section you refer to,

Comment: @musefan. I think he needs the two cases, doesn't he?

Comment: @gdoron: My assumption is that when he says "it'll be escaped" he means that the loop will skip to the next item (i.e. `continue;`) so he therefore doesn't care for any img that has an alt value

Comment: @musefan. Well, It's up to the OP, he can read your comments, and choose what he wants. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: tnx a lot, yes i need both cases cuz some image have the alt but it's empty

Comment: @gdoron: Yes I was right, OP wants images that have either no alt or an empty string alt. He doesn't care about the images that already have an alt. using `alt==''` will match this requirement

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started:

```
$("#body img").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if (!$this.attr("alt")){
     //do something
   }
});
```

Comment: Please, use `this.alt` instead of `$(this).attr('alt')`

Comment: @gdoron I'm assuming the OP will be making use of `$this` again, so it would be better to store this as a local variable, would it not?

Comment: No, because `$this.attr('alt)` is a lot slower than `this.alt` and a lot verbose.

Comment: And actually `$(this)` isn't an expensive operation as you may think. [You can read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179)

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys($('body').find('img')).map((item)=>{
    return $('body').find('img')[item].alt
})
```

By This method you can get all the image alt which are empty and also you ill get image tag which all are don't have alt attributes.